# The Efficacy and Behavior of the African Union

Tags: africa, summary-request, african-union

I'm interested in a summary of the political reality of the African Union, what it wants to do, what it actually does, and how effective it is at accomplishing it's goals.

I've gotten the sense that it's similar to the United Nations in that it's an official body without much real power over member states. But is there any more to it than that? Does it play a significant role on the African continent in any way?

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_Union ? What extra info do you need?  To some extent the AU seems to be very much the same kinda beastie as the Council of Europe, Arab League, OAS, ASEAN.  I.e. a talk shop for regional countries to engage in dialog in.  *"official body without much real power over member states"*.  Yes, like all the afore mentioned.  With possibly a free trade deal to boot.  Is that not sufficient, as long as it doesn't cost too much to run itself? (i.e. not jobs for the boys as cushy sinecures at taxpayer costs).

Comment: Reading the Wikipedia entry on the UN would also be useful. The UN has a lot of agencies, organisations, courts, training bodies, standards organisations, and other groups working on a wide variety of things, far beyond what the African Union does.